# Idris, convert from a Double to a Nat by dropping the decimal points (floor)

Tags: double, nat, idris, floor

In Idris, how to convert from a Double to a Nat by floor, dropping the decimal points.
I tried cast:

```
cast {to=Nat} num
```

However did not work.

```
When checking an application of function Main.takeLeftOfHalfLength:
        Can't cast from Double to Nat
```

Well that's to be expected as its not very explicit how the cast would work, loss of information.

However I still wish to cast from Double to Nat, how can it be done?

---

I discovered divNat function which lets me divide a Nat, but I'll leave the question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `floor`, cast to `Integer` and then use `integerToNat`:

```
Main> integerToNat $ cast {to = Integer} $ floor 3.9
3
```

Similarly `ceiling` can be used to get the rounded up `Nat`:

```
Main> integerToNat $ cast {to = Integer} $ ceiling 3.9
4
```